# C# Empty console window, small calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

Beginner here. Wanted to make a "calculator" for a cylinder with some user input. However, when I run my code I get a blank black [box](http://puu.sh/w5IOa/755bc02620.png). Can someone explain why my code doesn't work the way it is.

Thanks

```
        decimal pi = 3.1415926m; // well I guess it's long enough
        string userInputHeight = Console.ReadLine(); // first userInput
        decimal h = Convert.ToDecimal(userInputHeight); // h for height
        string userInputRadius = Console.ReadLine(); // second userInput 
        decimal r = Convert.ToDecimal(userInputRadius); // r for radius
        decimal V = pi * r * 2 * 2 * h; // formular for volumue of a cylinder. Didn't know how to use the '^' sign. So I decided to use 2*2 instead.
        decimal SA = 2 * pi * r * (r + h); // formular for the surface area of the cylinder.

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Cylinders! \n Please type first the height of your cylinder and confirm with spacebar " + userInputHeight); // Welcomes the user and asks for the height
        Console.ReadKey(); // waits for user input (in this case spacebar, but it doesn't matter which key is pressed)
        Console.WriteLine("Please type now the radius of your cylinder and confirm with spacebar " + userInputRadius); // Asks the user for the radius
        Console.ReadKey(); // waits for user input (in this case spacebar, but it doesn't matter which key is pressed)
        Console.WriteLine("The volume of your cylinder equals " + V + " and" + " the surface area equals " + SA); // this is where the magic happens.  
        Console.ReadKey(); // waits for user input (in this case spacebar, but it doesn't matter which key is pressed)
        Console.WriteLine("That's it! Press any key to close."); // closes with any key the window
```

Comment: Because you read from the console before you ever write anything? Try debugging and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Your code, in `Main`, will run from top to bottom. Every call to `Console.ReadLine()` will be executed at the place where it "stands". to fix it, put the `ReadLines` at the places where you want the user to perform input.

Comment: Please see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the user input before printing the messages. The correct flow is as follows:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Cylinders! \n Please type first the height of your cylinder and confirm with spacebar " + userInputHeight); // Welcomes the user and asks for the height
    string userInputHeight = Console.ReadLine(); // first userInput
    decimal h = Convert.ToDecimal(userInputHeight); // h for height
    Console.WriteLine("Please type now the radius of your cylinder and confirm with spacebar " + userInputRadius); // Asks the user for the radius  
    string userInputRadius = Console.ReadLine(); // second userInput 
    decimal r = Convert.ToDecimal(userInputRadius); // r for radius
    decimal V = Math.PI * r * 2 * 2 * h; // formular for volumue of a cylinder. Didn't know how to use the '^' sign. So I decided to use 2*2 instead.
    decimal SA = 2 * Math.PI * r * (r + h); // formular for the surface area of the cylinder.
    Console.WriteLine("The volume of your cylinder equals " + V + " and" + " the surface area equals " + SA); // this is where the magic happens.  
    Console.ReadKey(); // wait's for user input (in this case spacebar, but it doesn't matter which key is pressed)
    Console.WriteLine("That's it! Press any key to close."); // closes with any key the window
```

Also, do not use your own defined pi. Use Math.PI instead.

Comment: Good to mention `Math.PI`